# Trying to build a delete button in PHP for each row but there's an error

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying with the following code in PHP for generating row and delete button. But instead of deleting the selected ones, it deletes from the bottom of the row.

```php
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','rohit');
{

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id     = $row['id'];
        $name   = $row['name'];
        $lname  = $row['lname'];
        $dept   = $row['department'];
        $dob    = $row['DOB'];
        $doj    = $row['DOJ'];
        $mobile = $row['mobile'];
        $email  = $row['email'];
        $salary = $row['salary'];
        $gender = $row['gender'];


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$id}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$lname}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$dept}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$dob}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$doj}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$mobile}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$email}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$salary}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$gender}</td>";
        echo '<td>' . '<form method="post"><button class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" name="edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>' .
            '<button class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-danger" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></form>'
            . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}

?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $query1  = "DELETE FROM user ";
    $query1 .= "WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$query1);

    if (!$result1) {
        die("FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
?>
```

Any kind of help is appreaciated.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `"WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1"` - Where are you defining `$id`? You should also look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of injecting the user data directly into the queries like that.

Comment: Is the code for the delete button executed at all? I can see that there is a button for delete, but that form is using `method="post"` while your `if`-statement are looking for `$_GET['delete']`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry I was trying with a different code from a different post that's why I put the `$_GET['delete']` their, there actually `$_POST['delete']` and it deletes from the bottom.

Comment: Ok, but where are you defining the variable `$id` which you use in the query? I don't even see you passing any id through the form at all?

Comment: I am fetching the id from the table just after the `While()` function. At the top `$id     = $row['id'];`

Comment: Considering that you overwrite the variables in your loop on each iteration, the `$id` will always contain the id of the last post. You need to pass the id in the form and use that value instead.

Comment: **Warning!** Your code is _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! Look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank so much, I'll use parameterized statements.

Comment: You have to pass id as a hidden field at the time of delete and use this id in delete query .. also change $_GET['delete']  to  $_POST['delete'] . this will works .

Comment: Unless there's a legal requirement, don't allow users to DELETE data. Instead, allow them to UPDATE a 'visibility' flag to be 0.

Answer (score 2):

In your **form** you need to pass **action** attribute with the **id** of row that you want to delete

so it would be something like that

```
<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?id={$id}">
```

then in your SQL query, you will pass this id and I use here prepared statement to protect you from SQL injection

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
     $stmt = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE id=?");
     $stmt->bind_param($_GET['id']);
     $stmt->execute();

   if (!$result1) {
    die("FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: yah i know other users write that for him in comments, but at all, I will edit my answer to

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i fix my answer i think it looks good now thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in your code. This will works..!!

1.changed method Attribute (Given form method POST , but in php query it is GET. Now both POST type)

2.passed id as hidden field at the time of delete. So it will delete ,correct record.Also delete query is change (use this id for delete the record)

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','rohit');
{

$query  = "SELECT * FROM user";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id     = $row['id'];
    $name   = $row['name'];
    $lname  = $row['lname'];
    $dept   = $row['department'];
    $dob    = $row['DOB'];
    $doj    = $row['DOJ'];
    $mobile = $row['mobile'];
    $email  = $row['email'];
    $salary = $row['salary'];
    $gender = $row['gender'];


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$id}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$lname}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$dept}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$dob}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$doj}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$mobile}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$email}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$salary}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$gender}</td>";
    echo '<td>' . '<form method="post"><button class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" name="edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>' .
        '<input type="hidden" name="del_id" value="'.$id.'">'.
        '<button class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-danger" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></form>'
        . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";

}
}

?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$del_id = $_POST['del_id'];
$query1  = "DELETE FROM user ";
$query1 .= "WHERE id = $del_id LIMIT 1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$query1);

if (!$result1) {
    die("FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
}
?>
```

Comment: **Warning!** This code is _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! It should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in the queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `$id` that you used to get data from `$result` object in while loop. The loop ended at the last present id in your database so it will only delete the last `$id` and only once. You can write `$id` of each record in your form. For example:

```
<form method="post"><button class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-primary" name="edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>' .
    '<input display="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">'.
    '<button class="mb-1 mr-1 btn btn-danger" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</form>
```

and then in your PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $d_id = $_POST['id'];
    $query1  = "DELETE FROM user ";
    $query1 .= "WHERE id = $d_id LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$query1);
}
```